# after a few seconds an image has been clicked, open a link

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have already tried a lot, but did not come to an optimal solution. I have an image (html) and would like that if you press/click the image 5 seconds long, that he opens a link.

So far I have this code:

```
if (...) { window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xBz5k/

Comment: Let me see if I understand, you want to hold your click in the image for 5 seconds and then open a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the other answers open the link 5 seconds *after* a simple click. This one opens the link if the click lasted 5 seconds:

```
// the gif
var imgAnimation = '/images/animation.gif';
// the original image
var imgInitial = '/images/still.jpg';
// preload the gif
(new Image()).src = imgAnimation;
var imageMouseDown;
// mouse button gets pressed
$('#image').mousedown(function() {
    $(this).prop('src', imgAnimation);
    // start the timeout
    imageMouseDown = setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
    }, 5000);
});

// when the mouse button gets released
$('#image').mouseup(function() {
    // the timeout isn't fired yet -> clear it
    if (imageMouseDown) {
            // set the old image again
            $(this).prop('src', imgStill);
        clearTimeout(imageMouseDown);
    }
});
```

Here's a demo including the changing image: http://jsfiddle.net/7Qugn/

Comment: Thank you! The reason why is, that I want that he starts an gif-animation (should start while clicking), which takes 5 seconds. I know it's not fair, but: How can I start the .gif-image also on clicking?

Comment: you can change the src of the image when the user clicks: First the src is some placeholder (eg the first frame of the gif), when the click occurs, it gets replaced and the animation starts. I can add it later to my answer, don't have time now :)

Comment: Ok, that would be great!! :)

Comment: Germany. Because of the image? :) I just googled a GIF and found the other image on the same page.

Comment: Achso :) In Deutsch wäre das wohl etwas einfacher gewesen ;) Bin dir auf jeden Fall sehr dankbar!

Comment: Nächstes mal dann auf deutsch :)

Comment: @John you should not edit the questions to notify about your comments. `Take a look to the comments ;)` If you have anything important rather post them as answer if they answers the question

Answer (score 0):

Use [**setTimeout**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) in click event handler.

Comment: This opens the link 5 seconds, *after* the user clicked it. The question was to open the link if the user pressed the link *for* 5 seconds

Comment: @John: See my answer, this should solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19959967/1682509

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout should do the trick

Using jQuery:

```
$('#linkImg').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href="http://google.com";
    },5000);
});
```

Comment: "This opens the link 5 seconds, after the user clicked it. The question was to open the link if the user pressed the link for 5 seconds", Reeno

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a javascript answer, you could do:

```
document.getElementById('random-image').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
  }, 1000);
}, false);
```

I've [created a JSFiddle for you (CLICK HERE)](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardorb/xBz5k/3/), to illustrate the behavior.

Comment: Perfect! Without jQuery ;) But:"This opens the link 5 seconds, after the user clicked it. The question was to open the link if the user pressed the link for 5 seconds", Reeno

Comment: That's why I posted a comment in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution if you want to click *and hold* the image

```
var timeout = 0;

$('img').mousedown(function() {
  timeout = setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
});

function myFunction() {
  window.location.href="http://google.com";
}
```